# ansible trying to read a folder

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci

Im trying to run ansible playbook on gitlab docker runner

here is .gitlab-ci:

```
clean-runners:
  extends: .runner:template   
  stage: manage-runners
  image:
    name: $IMAGE_REGISTRY/kubernetes/kubespray:v2.16.0
  variables:
    ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: "False"
  script:
    # - pwd 
    # - ls -la
    # - cd runner_cleaner
    # - env
    # - echo $KUBERNETES_USER_KEY
    - ansible-playbook --become -e @$VARIABLES -i $INVENTORY --private-key $KUBERNETES_PRIVATE runner_cleaner/task.yaml -vvvvv
  when: manual
```

but job is finishing with code 1:

```
$ ansible-playbook --become -e @$VARIABLES -i $INVENTORY --private-key $KUBERNETES_PRIVATE runner_cleaner/task.yaml -vvvvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.20
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) [GCC 8.4.0]
No config file found; using defaults
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /builds/volkov_pm/ansible/hosts.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /builds/volkov_pm/ansible/hosts.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /builds/volkov_pm/ansible/hosts.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /builds/volkov_pm/ansible/hosts.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /builds/volkov_pm/ansible/hosts.ini inventory source with ini plugin
ERROR! an error occurred while trying to read the file '/builds/volkov_pm/ansible': [Errno 21] Is a directory: b'/builds/volkov_pm/ansible'
```

at first i was thinking that there is a problem with playbook location but `ls` and `pwd` show that everything is fine. I've even check wrong location to be sure and as excepted it give an error  `the playbook could not be found`. So it SEES playbook and inventory files but for some reason trying to read current folder.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a _hosts.ini_ in that folder? It seems like Ansible declines to parse it. Without knowing the content of it, there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, it not declined. ini plugin succesfully parsed it. (2nd line from the bottom)

Comment: Have you simply tested providing _/builds/volkov_pm/ansible/hosts.ini_ as your inventory to Ansible, rather than the folder, then (an so as your `INVENTORY` variable)?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, yes. Full path for key file, for invenory file and even playbook file. It doesn't raise any error about absence any of them. But still trying to read dir for some reason

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε i dont understand the reason... but i just move ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING variable from ci/script to hosts.ini and it works for me